# fetch async и Promise.all()

Tags: promise, fetch

Вчера работало, сегодня уже нет.

```
var fd = new URLSearchParams();
function loot(){
    return fetch('https://loot.farm/fullprice.json', { method: "GET", cache: "no-cache" }).then(response=>response.json());
};

function skinsjar(){
    return fetch('https://skinsjar.com/api/v3/load/bots?refresh=0&v=2', { method: "GET", cache: "no-cache" }).then(response=>response.json());
};

function csmoney(){
    return fetch('https://cs.money/load_bots_inventory', { method: "GET", cache: "no-cache" }).then(response=>response.json());
};

function tradeskins(){
    return fetch('https://trade-skins.com/load_all_bots_inventory', { method: "GET", cache: "no-cache" }).then(response=>response.json());
};

function swap(){
    return fetch('https://csgoswap.com/api/inventory/bot', { method: "POST", cache: "no-cache" }).then(response=>response.json());
};

function bot(){
    fd.set('who', 'bot');
    return fetch('https://www.thecsgobot.com/api/service.inventory.json', { method: "POST", cache: "no-cache", body: fd }).then(response=>response.json());
};
function start(data){
    //обработка
};
Promise.all([skinsjar(), tradeskins(), swap(), bot(), loot(), csmoney()]).then(results=> start(results));
```

ошибка `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: где-то вместо JSON вам возвращается HTML.

Comment: @etki действительно, 1 из сайтов ушел на переработку и там html сообщение об этом.

Comment: @etki поможешь с 1 проблемой? Мне надо получить примерно 10000 данных с 1 сайта с разными GET параметрами, но как понимаешь без async это будет долго, а делать promise приводит к `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`, как быть?